# How to delete a network interface?

Tags: unix, networking

I tried to create an IPIP tunel using the ip tunnel add command. Now I want to delete it but it won't go away!

```
tunl0     Link encap:IPIP Tunnel  HWaddr   
          NOARP  MTU:1480  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

$ sudo ifdown tunl0
ifdown: interface tunl0 not configured
$ sudo ifconfig tunl0 down
$ /sbin/ip tunnel del tunl0
delete tunnel tunl0 failed: Operation not permitted
```

What should I do?

Comment: Can *you* spot the difference between the three commands?

Comment: No. I was just trying a bunch of stuff to delete the interface. The last command was executed as root if that is what you are referring to.

Comment: If the last command was executed as root, why is the prompt the usual `$` rather than `#`? Why was the operation not permitted? Double-check or triple-check. :)

Comment: Burhan 's linked answer addresses an unwanted `gre0` device.  As with the `tunl0` device, these fallback interfaces go away when the kernel module is removed - in this case `ipip` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really programming related (it needs to go to serverfault.com). It was answered here: https://serverfault.com/questions/247767/cannot-delete-gre-tunnel